# Auto style checkbox with jQuery ui theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

(jQuery noob here)

Im trying to write a script which when I write `<input type='checkbox'/>` will automatically convert it to jQuery UI button and look like a checkBox.
Sample code so far ...

```
var newCheckboxID = 0;
$( "input:checkbox" ).attr('id', "cbx-" + nextCheckboxID++); // how to do that?
$( "input:checkbox" ).after("<label style='width:16px; height:16px; vertical-align:middle;'></label>");
$( "input:checkbox" ).next().attr("for", $(this).attr('id') ); // doesn't work for sure
$( "input:checkbox" ).button();
$( "input:checkbox" ).button( "option", "text", false );
$( "input:checkbox" ).attr("onclick", "$(this).button( 'option', 'icons', {primary:((this.checked)?'ui-icon-check':null),secondary:null} )");
```

Sorry, if it's too obvious but I've lost more than hour in that ...

### **EDIT**

Finally did it with the old fashioned way (for the doesn't working parts).
Any comments for making it more compact and "more jQuery" would be appriciated ...
Code sample

```
// ---- set ids
var checkboxID = 0;
//$( "input:checkbox" ).attr('id', "cbx-" + nextCheckboxID++); // how to do that?
var cboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');           // <-- do this instead
for(var i=0; i<cboxes.length; i++){
    if( cboxes[i].getAttribute('type')!='checkbox' ) continue;
    cboxes[i].setAttribute('id', 'cbx-'+checkboxID++);}

// ---- add labels
$( "input:checkbox" ).after("<label style='width:16px; height:16px; vertical-align:middle;'></label>");
//$( "input:checkbox" ).next().attr("for", $(this).attr('id') ); // doesn't work this
for(var i=0; i<cboxes.length; i++){                              // <-- do this instead
    if( cboxes[i].getAttribute('type')!='checkbox' ) continue;
    cboxes[i].nextSibling.setAttribute('for', cboxes[i].getAttribute('id') );}

// ---- create
$( "input:checkbox" ).button();
$( "input:checkbox" ).button( "option", "text", false );
$( "input:checkbox" ).attr("onclick", "$(this).button( 'option', 'icons', {primary:((this.checked)?'ui-icon-check':null),secondary:null} )");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Working examples:

- [jsFiddle (without comments)](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/AXuYL/)
- [jsFiddle (without comments with UI theme switcher!)](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/AXuYL/212/)
- [jsFiddle (with comments)](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/AXuYL/38/)
- [jsFiddle (Just for fun, uses timer and some other jQuery features, just for future reference)](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/b4jpmkw6/6/)
- [jsFiddle (Just for fun, uses timer and changes UI theme every second!)](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/AXuYL/213/show/)

In the following, I should note 2 primary changes.  I added CSS to do what you were trying to do to labels in "code" (where it really doesn't belong).

Also, I changed the HTML for "ease of jQuery" use. However, I still noted in the comments how you can easily change it back.

> the **HTML**

```
<center>
    <button>Create New CheckBox</button>
</center>
<hr />
<div id="CheckBoxes">
    <input class="inp-checkbox" />
    <input class="inp-checkbox" />
    <input class="inp-checkbox" />
    <input class="inp-checkbox" />
</div>​
```

> the **CSS**

```
.inp-checkbox+label {
    width:16px; 
    height:16px; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

> the **JavaScript/jQuery**

```
// keep in mind, and i will explain, some of these "moving-parts" or not needed, but are added to show you the "ease" of jquery and help you see the solution

//  This global function is designed simply to allow the creation of new checkboxes as you specified, however, if you won't be making check boxes at end user time, then i suggest simply moving it to within the .each statement found later on.
//  Also, this could easily be written as a jQuery plugin so that you could make a "chainable" one-line call to change checkboxes to this but let's get to the nitty gritty first
function createCheckBox(ele, i) {
    //  First I simply create the new ID here, of course you can do this inline, but this gives us a bottleneck for possible errors
    var newID = "cbx-"+i;
    //  below we use the param "ele" wich will be a jQuery Element object like $("#eleID")
    //  This gives us the "chainability" we want so we don't need to waste time writing more lines to recall our element
    //  You will also notice, the first thing i do is asign the "attribute" ID
    ele.attr({ "id": newID  })
        //  Here we see "chainability at work, by not closing the last line, we can move right on to the next bit of code to apply to our element
        //  In this case, I'm changing a "property", keep in mind this is kinda new to jQuery,
        //  In older versions, you would have used .attr but now jQuery distinguishes between "attributes" and "properties" on elements (note we are using "edge", aka. the latest jQuery version
        .prop({ "type": "checkbox" })
        //  .after allows us to add an element after, but maintain our chainability so that we can continue to work on the input
        // here of course, I create a NEW label and then immidiatly add its "for" attribute to relate to our input ID
        .after($("<label />").attr({ for: newID  }))
        //  I should note, by changing your CSS and/or changing input to <button>, you can ELIMINATE the previous step all together
        // Now that the new label is added, lets set our input to be a button,
        .button({ text: false }) // of course, icon only
        //  finally, let's add that click function and move on!
        //  again, notice jQuery's chainability allows us no need to recall our element
        .click(function(e) {
            //  FYI, there are about a dozen ways to achieve this, but for now, I'll stick with your example as it's not far from correct
            var toConsole = $(this).button("option", {
                icons: {
                    primary: $(this)[0].checked ? "ui-icon-check" : ""
                }
            });
            console.log(toConsole, toConsole[0].checked);
        });
    //  Finally, for sake of consoling this new button creation and showing you how it works, I'll return our ORIGINAL (yet now changed) element
    return ele;
}

$(function() {
    //  This .each call upon the inputs containing the class I asiged them in the html,
    //  Allows an easy way to edit each input and maintain a counter variable
    //  Thus the "i" parameter
    //  You could also use your ORIGINAL HTML, just change $(".inp-checkbox") to $("input:[type='checkbox']") or even $("input:checkbox")
    $(".inp-checkbox").each(function(i) {
        // as previously noted, we asign this function to a variable in order to get the return and console log it for your future vision!
        var newCheckBox = createCheckBox($(this), i);
        console.log(newCheckBox);
    });

    //  This next button added is simply to show how you can add new buttons at end-time
    //  ENJOY!!!
    $("button").button().on("click", function(e) {
        var checkBoxCount = $("#CheckBoxes .inp-checkbox").length;
        var newCheckBox = $("<input />").addClass("inp-checkbox").appendTo($("#CheckBoxes"));
        createCheckBox(newCheckBox , checkBoxCount);
        console.log(newCheckBox);
    });
});​
```

---

> Update: *The original intent here was to purely answer the question, which was to create a jQuery UI styled checkbox and show how jQuery can be used in multiple ways. However, a later comment queried how to include a traditional style label with it. While there are a billion options for this, I'll simply take from the above and extend.*

The first option I took is pretty simple. Using [`jsFiddle (without comments with UI theme switcher!)`](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/AXuYL/212/), I made the following changes:

> the **JavaScript/jQuery**

```
// First I add a new variable.
// It will simply be for a new "wrapper" element, in which to ensure our button is encased. 
// Giving this element a new class gives easy access for later CSS or Event Triggering of sub elements (like the checkbox)
var newID = "cbx-"+i,
    wrapper = $('<div />', { 'class': 'ui-checkbox-wrapper' }).appendTo('#CheckBoxes');
//  Then I added a line to our ele series of methods.
//  This line simply append our element (checkbox) to our new wrapper
// Take Note at how I added this method at start rather than at end.
// Had I not done this, then the label would not have been wrapped!
ele.appendTo(wrapper)   //  <-- new line!
    .attr({ "id": newID  })
```

Then I simply added the following CSS:

```
#CheckBoxes .ui-button .ui-button-text {
    background: #A9A9A9;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
    left: 19px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: 0;
    top: -4px;
}
```

## Results!

Comment: its not really a problem, really only took a few minutes, most of my time was spent "playing" :P, speaking of which, i added another link where i show more of jQuery's uses and "play" around with a timer, enjoy checking it out and g'luck to future endevours!

Comment: @ApollonDigital btw, welcome to StackOverflow, you're gonna love it here!

Comment: @SpYk3HH - awesome piece of code, only thing missing is this code as plugin (so it would easier to create checkbox `$("input:checkbox").checkbox();` or something as simple as this) or even integration with jqueryUI :) Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I've made a slight improvement to your first fiddle which someone may find useful. I found that when checking these styled checkboxes (which are awesome, by the way) the "checked" value of the original (see: submitted with the form) checkbox didn't change. Here's a new fiddle with my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/qFbnd/2/

Comment: I'v made a fix of this script, wasn't working as expected if the check-box was already checked during creation. -> http://jsfiddle.net/tx48S/

Comment: This is great and deserves more than 12 score, thanks.

Comment: The expected behavior is to be able to click on a LABEL and have the checkbox checked/unchecked. This script just adds an empty label. Of course you can add test into <input> tag, but it will not be clickable.

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko Not true. It works fine for me. I even made an alt version, giving text to the labels, and as you can see [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/b4jpmkw6/), works just fine. Could you explain what you're attempting to achieve and maybe we can solve your problem

Comment: I've tried your code. Here is what happened: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/lgweffX.png)
True for Opera and Chrome.

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko Uhm yeah. What's the problem? I'm using it in chrome, and yeah, the quick example with text in label is supposed to look like that. I don't see the problem?

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko I'm not sure your intention, but the whole point of this answer was to help OP better understand jQuery and how to use it to make a custom checkbox that could be created dynamically and still use the same event, and it does all that. Perhaps you should make a question?

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko And fyi, i almost use Chrome exclusivly, however, I have every other browser on my pc for testing, and all my fiddles work as expected in all of them, including safari and even opera

Comment: @SpYk3HH The problem is that if I saw this on a website as a user, I would leave it immediately.
1. The label is not on the right but right on top of the checkbox.
2. The width of the element is not expanded automatically according to the label length.
This way the checkboxes are way far from user-friendly.

Comment: @SpY3HH 3. The label disappears when you check the checkbox. So you need to dubpicate it.

Comment: Then you completely misunderstand the question and the answer. And you're still completely wrong about setup. You're not making any sense to me, sorry

Comment: @SpYk3HH could you be so kind and explain where exactly am I wrong?
This setup does not work, because a button without explaining text makes no sense.

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko oooooh! Now I see your issue! You're lost in the semantics. That would be the css. I'm a bit busy, but if you'll give me 24 hours I will find time to make a fiddle for you that will help you out. Maybe even add it to this answer, though that wasn't really the issue here. Gimmie lil time and I'll hook you up

Comment: @SpYk3HH actually, I've found a solution, which works for me:
(http://jsfiddle.net/b4jpmkw6/4/)
Your solution might be nicer, because I see the labels changing color on hover in your setup

Comment: @HelgaIliashenko So sry it's taken me so long. I've been super busy. Anyway. What you're getting lost on deals more with CSS. Most of this answer was teach simple use of jQuery and show how to make a graphic checkbox with it. If you notice, even in OP's question, he nevers makes reference to a "text" label to be used. Most would use this kind of checkbox in a table, thus the label would be a header of some sort. But if you need a checkbox like this with working label, you have a couple options. Recheck answer here in a few minutes

Comment: Thank you, SpYk3HH, this looks like an awesome solution!